# How to get last created directory in php?

Tags: php, cpanel

Dynamically I am creating sub directory in a folder and I need to get the last created directory in a sting format, I have tried many ways but failed to get it. What i have tried is,

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir";
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';
$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
$filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
$latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
$latest_filename = $entry;
 }
}
```

But it works for only file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: and $path is full url for my work because its another subdomain.

Comment: I have tried, but its not working too with is_dir()

Comment: So if i use url, then how can i get this? besides subdomain directory is in my home directory, then how can i get the dir without url?

Comment: You can't. HTTP doesn't expose metadata for directories, its optional for files and may be used to convey different semantics than creation time. A URL with a FTP scheme is slightly different. A url with a file scheme is different again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir";
$latest_mtime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            if (is_dir($file) && filemtime($file) > $latest_mtime) {
                $latest_mtime = filemtime($file);
                $latest_filename = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Also,
you can change the condition of the blacklist for:

```
if (!in_array($file, $blacklist) && substr($file, 0, 1) != ".") {
```

to exclude hidden directories (in unix-like sistems).

Comment: Sorry, it's $file. I was still editing the answer. Try it now.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if it should be filectime or filemtime. Try with both of them.

Comment: Did it work for you? On my machine the results are what I expected.

Comment: Yes, It works, but I changed something and then its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Started as comments - but there were so many!

> But it works for only file

change `is_file` to `is_dir`

> and $path is full url

$path in the above is not a URL, its a path. is_dir/is_file/filectime won't work for URLs

Also you've flagged this as cpanel which would be a reason for closing this as off-topic, but its not relevant to a coding problem. OTOH it does hint that this is not a MSWindows platform. On Unix and Linux, filectime() actually returns the filemtime. So the information it shows will not accurately reflect the **creation** time.